# Is there a plugin for VSCode to "learn" most used snippets?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm a frequent user of VS Code, and I find a little bit annoying the fact that when I'm using code snippets VS Code suggest me things I really don't use. For example, if I input `d`, VS suggest whatever instead of `div`.

Is there a plugin for that? a plugin to let VS Code to "learn" what I use the most?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the settings to put snippet suggestions on top. Settings --> Suggestions --> Snippet Suggestions or just add `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"` to settings.json([click the two curly braces at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTeMt.png)).

You can also change what is pre-selected in  ["suggest selection"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWGyT.png)